# Set JAVA_HOME programmatically to Conda installation of JDK

Tags: java, python, pyspark, java-home

I am trying to run a python script on a cloud hosted machine, where Java 11 is the default Java version.

I have a python library (Pyspark) which requires Java 8. However I have another library that requires Java 11.

Therefore I need to programmatically change my Java version while running the script.
The code that I think would solve my problem would like something like this:

```
program_that_requires_java11 = lib.create()

os.change_java_version('path/to/conda/installation/of/java8)

spark_context = pyspark.SparkContext('local')

os.change_java_version('path/to/java11/')
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Try doing `os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = '/path/to/your/jre/folder/'`

Comment: Normally, your python lib (which requires Java 8) should not have problems with Java 11. Can you specify your Java 11 problem? Maybe you don't need to change your environment variable and can just use Java 11.